# Integral of the exponential in the n dimensional ball

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, exponential-function, spherical-coordinates

I would like to calculate the integral $\int_{||\boldsymbol{x}||_{2}\leq \epsilon} e^{\boldsymbol{c}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}}d\boldsymbol{x}$ where $\boldsymbol{x}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\epsilon>0$, $\boldsymbol{c}\in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is rotationally symmetric, so you might as well take $\boldsymbol{c}$ along the positive $x$ axis and let its magnitude be $c$.  Then at each given $x$ the cross section is an $n-1$ dimensional ball of radius $\sqrt{2^2-x^2}$  Now your integral becomes $\int_{-2}^2e^{cx}\frac {\pi^{\frac {n-1}2}}{\Gamma(\frac n2-1)}(4-x^2)^{\frac {n-1}2}dx$.  [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%20e%5E(cx)(4-x)%5E((n-1)%2F2)) will do the integral in terms of the incomplete Gamma function.

Comment: Can we do anything similar for  $\int_{||\boldsymbol{x}||_{1}\leq \epsilon} e^{\boldsymbol{c}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}}d\boldsymbol{x}$ ?

Comment: Not so easily.  Are you still defining $\boldsymbol{c}^{T}\boldsymbol{x}$ as the usual dot product?  That plays nicely with the $2-$ norm, but not so much with the $1-$ norm.  Maybe you are just using the $1-$ norm to define  a hypercube volume.  The fact that the volume is not rotationally symmetric makes it much harder.

Comment: yes it is the hypercube volume